# How to hide result of FHE?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

Lets say we are given [BFV](https://inferati.com/blog/fhe-schemes-bfv) encryption of `x`, let this encryption is represented as `E(x)`. In FHE, the client can decrypt and get the value of `x` but what if we dont want the client to learn `x`. This [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/073.pdf) suggests that:

- the servers samples random `r` and perform `E(x)+r` and send that to client
- The client decrypts and get `x+r`
- The paper suggests that this is like a secret sharing of `x`. More concretely Server share is `r` and client share is `x+r mod p`. (p is plaintext mod)

My question is which ring r is sampled from ? is it from `R_p` or `R_q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\mathbf{r}$ serves as a one-time pad. So, it is sufficient to use a uniform $\mathbf{r}$ sampled from a vector space where the plaintext $\mathbf{x}$ is in. What really matters is how to add up the HE ciphertext $[\mathbf{x}]$ and the plaintext $\mathbf{r}$ to get a new HE ciphertext $[\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{r}]$. This operation is easy for any linear HE.

Comment: I understand that this vector is going to server as OTP. I am worried about the following issue, if encryption is `a, as+e+m \mod q` then after addition it will become `a, as+e+m+r mod q` the client who holds secret key could remove `as` so she gets `m+r+e mod q` I am not sure how this is OTP in mod q ? or am I missing something (I know m+r mod p is secure as its uniform )

Comment: I think that $\vec{m} + \vec{r} + \vec{e} \in R_q$ is only an intermediate result in the decryption of HE ciphertext $[\vec{m} + \vec{r}]$. For non-approximate HE schemes, the error should be then removed using the plaintext modulus. It may be helpful to view $(\vec{a}, \vec{a} \vec{s} + (\vec{m} + \vec{r}) + \vec{e})$ as the HE ciphertext for the plaintext $\vec{m} + \vec{r} \in R_p$ (which is the information can be learned by the client at most). Now, the OTP $\vec{r}$ works.

Comment: oh I see yea that makes it indeed easier